# basic ng-model is not working

Tags: angularjs

This is the basic code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

    <p>Input something in the input box:</p>

    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Input something in the input box:

Name : 

Hello {{name}}
```

Why is this happening and how should I fix this? This is where I am learning.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

I am trying to learn but got stuck on this very basic code.

Comment: It has to do with you not referencing your angular.js file correctly. Make sure you have your angular file where you say it should be in the `<script>`-tag. You can use the CDN path as well `<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I already have downloaded the angular.min.js and have referenced it according to my project directory path.

Comment: See if your path is correct. You can check in the network console for a 404

Comment: @AndersRehn and PSL there indeed was a 404 error in the console! I used the cdn before but it wasn't working then for some reason. But now its working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing your `ng-app` declaration followed by a controller with `ng-controller`. Here is a plunker [demo - click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FV2RqqRkthUBdSMtjreu?p=preview)

Or a single page code example (with script appended to the bottom):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myAppName">

<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>

<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</body>

<script>
// initialise your angular app:
var app = angular.module('myAppName', []);

// add controller:
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {  
  $scope.name = '';    
});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I had made a different js file with the above code and had included it in my html file. The problem was with including the angular.min.js file. Thank you.